# Return a new instance of Child class from base class static method

Tags: typescript

What I am stuck at:

I want a Base class which can return a new object of its child class.

like:

```
export class Base {
    constructor () {
    }

    static query() {
      //return a new object of class from which this function is called.
    }

}

export class Child extends Base {

}
```

now in my IndexComponent Class

```
export class IndexComponent {
 var user = Child.query() // By this I have a new object of Child class in user variable
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution is simple:

```
export class Base {
    constructor () {}

    static query() {
        return new this();
    }
}

let base = Base.query(); // Base {}
let child = Child.query(); // Child {}
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Base%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor%20()%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20static%20query()%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09return%20new%20this()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Child%20extends%20Base%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20base%20%3D%20Base.query()%3B%20%2F%2F%20Base%20%7B%7D%0D%0Alet%20child%20%3D%20Child.query()%3B%20%2F%2F%20Child%20%7B%7D))

This works because when executing a static function then the `this` is the constructor function.
You can see that in the compiled js:

```
var Base = (function () {
    function Base() {
    }
    Base.query = function () {
        return new this();
    };
    return Base;
}());
```

The `query` function is a property of `Base` constructor function, and will also be a property of `Child` because it extends `Base`.

The problem here is how to type this `query` function so that the compiler will know what is the returned type.
For now you'll need to do this:

```
let base = Base.query(); // here base is of type 'Base'
let child: Child = Child.query(); // need to declare the type
// or
let child2 = Child.query() as Child; // or assert it
```

I can't think of a way to make the compiler infer the right type which is returned, would love to know if anyone has an idea.

Comment: Thank you. I able to console the object of the child class.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have a similar situation, but my base class is abstract and the compiler gives me this error: `error TS2511: Cannot create an instance of the abstract class…`. How do I handle this? If I remove `abstract` keywords it works correctly.

Comment: More details is here: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5863

Comment: @SlavaFominII You'll probably need to cast `this` to something else